# know how to remove the milli seccond part (.%f) from the timestamp in Python

Tags: pandas

Hello I don't know how to remove the millisecond part (`.%f`) from the `timestamp`. I only want  the timestamp to be like `%H:%M:%S` not  `%H:%M:%S.%f`. For example, from `2018-06-29 08:15:27.243860` convert to `08:15:27`. If any one have an idea I am really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.to_datetime` and `floor`:

```
df['dt2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dt']).dt.floor('S')
print(df)

# Output
                           dt                 dt2
0  2018-06-29 08:15:27.243860 2018-06-29 08:15:27
```

If `dt` column is already a `DatetimeIndex`, just use `df['dt'].dt.floor('S')`.